# Why "Omit" utility from Typescript have extends any for "K"?

Tags: typescript

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

Since the parameter "K" of Omit extends keyof **any**, we have no error given by Typescript when insert a property name which does not exist in the parameter "T".

Omit helps to remove one property which is contained by a Type or Interface. I don't find it logical to freely insert a property that doesn't exist in the givin Type/Interface.

Isn't it better this way:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

What's the actual reason for Typescript to extends keyof any ? And how can I change it for my project ?

Comment: What does "Why doesn't the parameter K is a keyof any ?" mean, exactly?

Comment: `keyof any` is also essentially `PropertyKey` which is an alias for `string | number | symbol`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `K extends keyof any` allows for more flexible calls of `Omit` without having to modify the second type to include only properties that exist in the object. For example, using your version, you wouldn't be able to do:

```
type BadProps = 'bad1' | 'bad2' | 'bad3';
type Omit2<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type Result = Omit2<{ bad2: 'val2'}, BadProps>
```

You would have to first construct another type from `BadProps`. Not that that would be *hard*, but it'd add unnecessary boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Omit helps to remove one property which is contained by a Type or Interface. I don't find it logical to freely insert a property that doesn't exist in the givin Type/Interface.

Comment: @Sabgramar totally agree - if any of the "props" change its name, then the omitting won't happen and new type will be wrong - it'd break anyway, but on different and more propriate place ^^